# How to install pychm on windows 8

Tags: python, windows, chm

I am trying to learn about the python chm package and therefore trying to install pychm package on windows 8 as follows :

```
pip install pychm
```

This gives a lot of errors the last one being :

```
    chm/swig_chm.c(681) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chm_lib.h': No such file or directory
```

I need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: The error tells you that you don't have CHMLib installed on your system. And from what I can find it is a library that is used by GnoCHM which is for [gnome](http://freecode.com/projects/pychm)

Comment: Yes I am not able to install CHMLIB for windows. All the links that I found were for linux. I have no idea what to do

Comment: @Headhunter Xamd yes I am not ble to install CHMLIB for windows. All the links that I am finding are for linux. I have no idea what to do

Comment: it seems that all you can do is use a virtual machine with linux or use a live media usb with enough persistence to keep your changes and boot your computer on the device(you don't need to install it because of the persistence)